# Adding Authentication to Twisted

Tags: twisted

After extensive searching I have not been able to add authentication to my simple twisted site. The site accepts a web get and enumerates the arguments it is passed. This is what I am working with. There is only one user who needs to authenticate prior to accepting the web get request so I am not sure realm is applicable to this situation. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
from twisted.web import server, resource
from twisted.internet import reactor, task
class Simple(resource.Resource):
isLeaf = True
allowedMethods = ('GET',)

def render_GET(self, request):
    try:
        print(request)
        urlstring = request.content.read()
        print (urlstring)
        print (request.content.read())
        print request.args
        print "User=", request.getUser()
        print "Pass=", request.getPassword()

    except Exception, exception:
        print "Unexpected error", exception.args


    return "200 ok"

site = server.Site(Simple())
reactor.listenTCP(8080, site, interface='')
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP Authentication for Twisted Web is documented in https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/http-auth.html